# Formula for Gaussian High-pass Filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing

As far as I know, the formula to generate the Gaussian low-pass filter is:

```
[x y] = meshgrid(round(-N/2):round(N/2), round(-N/2):round(N/2));
GaussianFilter = exp((-x.^2/(2*sigma^2)-y.^2/(2*sigma^2)));
```

What should the formula for the high-pass filter be in this case?

Comment: the identity minus a lowpass filter = a high pass filter :)

Comment: do you mean we minus every value in lowpass filter matrix by one then it will becomes highpass filter :)

Comment: @Aptos Almost. You simply do `GaussianHPF = 1 - GaussianLPF` (I renamed `GaussianFilter` to `GaussianLPF` for clarity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I am writing is based off this- [MATLAB Image Sharpening - Gaussian High Pass Filter using (1- Gaussian Low Pass Filter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854228/matlab-image-sharpening-gaussian-high-pass-filter-using-1-gaussian-low-pass?rq=1) and the comments.

```
  GaussianFilterHigh  = 1 - exp((-x.^2/(2*sigma^2)-y.^2/(2*sigma^2)));
```