# MATLAB Image Sharpening - Gaussian High Pass Filter using (1- Gaussian Low Pass Filter)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I am trying to sharpen an image by designing a Gaussian High-Pass Filter. I would like to do this using the fact that the high-pass filter is equivalent to the identity matrix minus the low-pass filter, so I did the following:

```
image= imread('Question3_Data-Cats.jpg'); % read image

H = 1 - fspecial('gaussian' ,[5 5],2); % create unsharp mask
sharpened = imfilter(image,H);  % create a sharpened version of the image using that mask

imshow([image sharpened]); %showing input & output images
```

I did not get a sharpened image. Instead, I got a white image with some colors on a small region of the image. Can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: You're not subtracting the identity matrix, you're subtracting a matrix of ones.

Comment: I tried H = 255-fspecial('gaussian' ,[5 5],2); 
It did not work as well.

Comment: Have you tried eye()?

Comment: yup...it did not work as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
H = padarray(2,[2 2]) - fspecial('gaussian' ,[5 5],2); % create unsharp mask
```

1 is a scalar.  You need a 5x5 array with one in the center.  Furthermore, the filter elements must sum to one if you want to conserve brightness, so you need to double the central value to counter the amount you are subtracting.

Comment: okay this works, but I don't understand why. Can you elaborate more regarding why all elements are zero except the one in the middle. Also, what do you mean by "conserving the brightness".

Comment: You can view the action of a filter as replacing each pixel with a weighted sum of its neighbors.  The weight on each neighbor is given by the magnitude of the filter components.  The identity filter is a single one in the center of the filter -- meaning that the pixel's new value is exactly the same as its old value.  A Gaussian filter averages contributions from multiple pixels around the center, giving a blur effect.  If the filter values don't sum to 1.0, then the overall brightness will change -- brighter if they sum to more than 1, darker if they sum to less than 1.

Answer (score 6):

Let `g` be the `gaussian` kernel and `f` be the image. Then `f * g` (convolution) gives the blurred version of the image. That means `low-passed` version of the image.

Then consider [image: f - f \ast g]. It means `image - lowpass image`. That gives the `high-passed` version of the image. It contains only image details. The details are in white on the black background. I think that is the image you are getting right now.

[image: image detail]

After you have extracted the image details from the image, you have to add them back to the image to get a sharpened image.

[image: Sharpen Image]

That means you can get the sharpened image by convolution of `2e - g` with your image(This is the unsharp mask).

You can get `2e` from matlab using `padarray(2,[2 2])` and `g` using `fspecial('gaussian' ,[5 5],2)`.

```
H = padarray(2,[2 2]) - fspecial('gaussian' ,[5 5],2); %create unsharp mask
```

Sometimes, you will need to control the brightness of the image details. You can do that by

> sharpen image = image + alpha(image details)

[image: control brightness of image details]

Answer (score -1):

```
I= imread('peppers.png'); % read image
H = padarray(2,[2 2]) - fspecial('gaussian' ,[5 5],2); % create unsharp mask % create unsharp mask
figure,imshow(I);
K = imfilter(I,H);  % create a sharpened version of the image using that mask
figure,imshow(K); %showing input & output images
```